# Qt Quick Window Minimize Event

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm writing my own desktop widget as practice. 
I need it to stay always on desktop and disable minimization.

The window is a Qt Quick `ApplicationWindow`. I can't find out how to catch the events when it is minimized. For example when I press minimize all windows button, then I see only desktop but I want to let my widget stay unminimized.

I tried to use signals in both QML and C++ but didn't succeed in it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to post the code as minimum and complete example. What's the term for that? What you want is doable for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit#1:** I've [uploaded](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/eventfilter-41780056) the code to GitHub.

You can install an event filter to handle the required event. In this case, the event you need to handle is `QEvent::WindowStateChange`.

Install the event filter on your main object. The following example is using `QQmlApplicationEngine` but you could use `QQuickView` instead.

The idea is to send a signal from C++ to your QML application and show again the window. I.e. by calling the [`show()`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#methods) method.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "myeventfilter.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyEventFilter filter;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    app.installEventFilter(&filter);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject::connect(&filter,
                     SIGNAL(windowStateChange()),
                     engine.rootObjects().takeFirst(),
                     SLOT(windowStateChange()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    function windowStateChange()
    {
        console.log("qml slot - windowStateChange");
        show();
    }
}
```

**myeventfilter.h**

```
#ifndef MYEVENTFILTER_H
#define MYEVENTFILTER_H

#include <QObject>

class MyEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyEventFilter(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

signals:
  void windowStateChange();
};

#endif // MYEVENTFILTER_H
```

**myeventfilter.cpp**

```
#include "myeventfilter.h"
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>

MyEventFilter::MyEventFilter(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

bool MyEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Close)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " QEvent::Close ";
        return false;
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << " QEvent::WindowStateChange ";
        emit windowStateChange();
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Frameless Window which will remove the minimize, expand and close buttons. Example is available [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html)